# Can't get simple Sass task to complete in Gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, task

I'm new to Gulp and was attempting to convert my Sass to CSS via a simple Gulp task.

I've tried the following (return statement):

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

//Compile Sass to CSS
function sass() {
    return gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'));
  };
```

and (done)

```
//Complie Sass to CSS
function sass(done) {
    gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'))
    done();
  };
```

But both return with

```
[18:38:07] The following tasks did not complete: sass
[18:38:07] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I figured using the return statement or the done parameter would complete the task. I can't figure out why it's telling me the taks can't be completed.

I also have a very similar CSS minify task running (hence the uglify variable) that is working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Try renaming your function to something different than `sass`.  Now the task is probably trying to call itself.

Comment: That worked! Strange because even in some videos or documentation I found, the function name seemed to be the same. Anyway, glad it's working. Thanks!